# Pass and append JavaScript Window methods?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure how to ask this, which may be why I can't find an answer or it's just not possible.

I want to pass in a JavaScript Window object method; is that possible?

Here's an example:

```
function change(winObj) {
     document.getElementById('someButton').winObj = function() { // whatever };

   //Could be equivalent to:
   //document.getElementById('someButton').onclick = function() { // whatever };
   //OR
   //document.getElementById('someButton').onmouseover = function() { // whatever };
   //...etc.
}
```

I'm not looking for a jQuery, or pure JS solution; I just want to know if what I'm showing is possible if tweaked somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add a use case? it's hard to understand what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean you wanted to specify the handler? Then use the bracket notation:

```
function change(eventName) {
  document.getElementById('someButton')[eventName] = function() {
    //whatever
  };
}
```

You can also use the standard `addEventListener` which is more appropriate:

```
function change(eventName) {
  document.getElementById('someButton').addEventListener(eventName,function{
    //whatever
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I was close. I had used the addEventListener one, but didn't know the syntax for appending a window method directly with brackets like your first example showed (that's just what I needed). Thank you!